# 80s scifi story about parasites feeding on emotions

Tags: story-identification

I read a story back in the 80s (approximately 1988) about a crew who was trying to stop criminals who were trained to use mental powers. Some of the population used a parasite that fed off of emotion and fed back good feelings.  In the end, the main bad guys were stopped by a device that would make them comatose when they would use their mental powers and their parasites ended up feeding on them.